# Can I use query_string to filter result before scoring for performance for Elasticsearch 1.5?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm writing an API on top of Elasticsearch 1.5 for people to be able to filter the documents before scoring from `query_string`. This is the my query

```
"query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {

                    "query": {
                        "bool": {
                            "must_not": [{
                                "query_string": {
                                    "query": "url:/.*valid_url.*/"
                                }
                            }],
                            "must": {
                                "terms": {
                                    "brand": ["the brand"]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

            },
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
            }
        }
    }
```

However, in order to use `query_string` I need to put that under `query` after `filtered.filter` I'm not sure if that would count as filter documents before scoring for performance?

I have about 6 million documents so from the query above, does it mean it will filter all the 6 million documents with `brand` equals to `the brand` and the `url` must not be `/.*valid_url.*/` using regular expression? And whatever's left from the filter will be scored but in this case it will be `match_all`?

Comment: Yes, that's what your query is telling, indeed. Do you get different results than expected?

Comment: I get the result I expected. I'm just afraid about the performance impact if the query wasn't filter before doing the query.